# Is an Arch-based distribution a valid option for my old Pentium M (fam-6 model-13) cpu with a 40 gig drive?

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, dual-boot, upgrade, 32bit

If so what flavor would be recommended ? (I have cross-posted this to superuser since I an confused about my hardware limitations) http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jbQQJ9PSC8/ http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/M7P2ZrYHRs/ http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/M7P2ZrYHRs/

A friend will help me edit this into an answerable question in case I am being too vague. It was suggested to ask the question here after I had already made the Super-User post.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, the Pentium M is a family of 32-bit processors. This limits the flavor of Arch Linux to one supporting the 32-bit architecture. Arch Linux has been 64-bit only for some years now, but there is Arch Linux 32 (https://archlinux32.org/), a "community maintained continuation of 32-bit support for Arch Linux".

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since cross-posting is discouraged, I would recommend that you delete your post over at SuperUser.

Comment: Please include the text in pastebin to your question. Questions should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

An Arch based distro is a viable choice. A popular one is Manjaro. Although, you must use a DE which isn't too intense on resources, like XFCE, or use a window manager, like i3.

[Link to Manjaro Download](https://manjaro.org/download/)

This link will lead you to the official supported versions of Manjaro. There's no harm looking at community versions. The only difference between them is Desktop Environments and/or Window Managers as well as some of them using previous versions of Manjaro. Check it out and see if it's for you.

Once you're confident with Linux, you could try using Arch itself. Here's a tip if you want to dive into Arch but don't want to use a command line: You can use a script called `archfi`, which is on Github. Just search 'archfi github' if you want to look into it. There are quite a few YouTube videos on the subject, although they may be outdated. **But only install Arch if you're confident in your abilities. If you're new, Manjaro is a good start.**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Arch Linux distro is far from user-friendly and I wouldn't recommend it to inexperienced users.

Your CPU is seemingly 32bit only, so you might want to install a distro which still supports x86 natively and is light on resources. My recommendation would be Xubuntu 18.04 LTS 32-bit: https://xubuntu.org/download/

Lastly, if you have 1GB of RAM or less and intend to browse the Internet, your experience will be far from stellar. Modern web browsers pretty much require you to have at the very least 2GB of RAM, unless you're OK with having a single web page open.

Comment: A bit unnecessary, but I'd like to point it out. They said Arch BASED. Still a good answer though!